# how to open .dwg files?

Tags: eclipse, file, autocad, android-image

I am writing an application to open and read a .dwg file in android os.
the IDE I am using is eclipse

I wanted to know if I had the source code of a reader or a . har file, then how to include it in my application.

Can somebody help?

Comment: -1 for unnecessary use of caps. fix it and i will take -1 off.

Comment: Please mark as answered,based on which you find is the correct answer.This may help others.

Comment: -1: Ditch the caps and the attitude.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert it (dwg/dfx) into pdf and then use a pdf viewer to view it in android